# How to compare values within a list and method?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have a LinkedList with different types of data which I need to handle in order to make a comparison and add the values that agree with the scope. More explanation will be given below,

`LinkedList` is filled with data of **Record class:**

```
class Record {
    public int id;
    public Point location; 
    public double score; 
    (...)
}
```

**Point class:**

```
class Point {
    public double x, y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double dist(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x-p.x)*(this.x-p.x)+(this.y-p.y)*(this.y-p.y));
    }
```

**RankList class:**

```
class RankList {

    private Node first;
    private int nodeCount;
    private Record record;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RankList list = new RankList();
        Point point = new Point(5.4, 3.2);
        Record record = new Record(1, point, 8.2);
        System.out.println(list.insert(record));
        double maxDist=point.dist(point);

        Point point1 = new Point(1.4, 9.2);
        Record record1 = new Record(2, point1, 7.5);
        if((point1.dist(point)>maxDist)) maxDist=point1.dist(point);
        System.out.println(list.insert(record1));

        Point point2 = new Point(2.2, 1.2);
        Record record2 = new Record(3, point2, 6.0);
        if((point2.dist(point1)>maxDist)) maxDist=point2.dist(point1);
        System.out.println(list.insert(record2));
        list.nearest(point1,maxDist);
```

I 've inserted some values to the list and let's say that I have some distance values between the given points like:

```
Distance between two points:
A->B = 3.2455
B->C = 7.345 
C->D = 2.111 
D->E = 8.056
```

From that the `maxDist` value is 8.059

Now I have to write the method `public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist)`  which finds all the distance values between the scope **(<=maxDist)** and return them in a list with the rest node values. So I need to calculate the distance with the pointers of the LinkedList and the given `Point p` argument, and add them to a new list.

My problem is if can I access the `LinkedList` which is already fulfilled with values and copy what I need to the new list structure.

**Method nearest:**

```
public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist){
            RankList nearList = new RankList();
            Node current = first;
            System.out.print("HEAD -> ");
            while (current != null) {
                System.out.print(current);
                System.out.print(" -> ");
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println("null");
            return null;
       }
```

I've tried to run the whole `LinkedList` with the traditional way but I stack on how to make the comparisons and add them to the new list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `RankList` class and `first` variable/field? Can you paste the whole class with the `nearest` method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused with your code. I cant find any `LinkedList` in it. Your class `RankList` seems to have only three fields and none of them is of the List type. I'm not sure what does the `insert` method does.

It is not the best idea to have fields in the class with the `main` method. It would be better if you prepare another class that runs the program.

I'd like to show how I'd write the code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I don't want the list to be a field of the class.
        RecordsList list = new RecordsList();

        // Following code blocks could be extracted as separate methods
        Point point = new Point(5.4, 3.2);
        Record record = new Record(1, point, 8.2);
        list.add(record);
        double maxDist = point.dist(point);

        Point point1 = new Point(1.4, 9.2);
        Record record1 = new Record(2, point1, 7.5);
        if((point1.dist(point)>maxDist)) maxDist=point1.dist(point);
        list.add(record1);

        Point point2 = new Point(2.2, 1.2);
        Record record2 = new Record(3, point2, 6.0);
        if((point2.dist(point1)>maxDist)) maxDist=point2.dist(point1);
        list.add(record2);

        Point farPoint = new Point(50, 50);
        Record recordWithFarPoint = new Record(4, farPoint, 5);
        list.add(recordWithFarPoint);

        RecordsList nearestList = list.nearest(point1, 20);
        for (Record rec : nearestList.getList()) {
            System.out.println(rec.id + " " + rec.location.x + " " + rec.location.y + " " + rec.score);
        }
        /*
         * On console:
         * 2 1.4 9.2 7.5
         * 1 5.4 3.2 8.2
         * 3 2.2 1.2 6.0
         */
    }

}

/**
 * This class is so-called wrapper on ArrayList.
 */
class RecordsList {
    // This may be called delegate.
    private ArrayList<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Record record) {
        this.list.add(record);
    }

    // This creates shallow copy.
    public ArrayList<Record> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public RecordsList nearest(Point p, double maxDistance) {
        RecordsList list = new RecordsList();

        List<Record> records = this.getList().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(oldListElement -> oldListElement.location.dist(p)))
                .filter(element -> element.location.dist(p) <= maxDistance)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Record record : records) {
            list.add(record);
        }

        return list;
    }

}

class Record {
    public int id;
    public Point location;
    public double score;

    public Record(int id, Point location, double score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.score = score;
    }

}

class Point {

    public double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double dist(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x - p.x) * (this.x - p.x) + (this.y - p.y) * (this.y - p.y));
    }

}
```

There are some concepts that may be new for you. The most complicated one is propably streamApi. You may read more about it i.e. here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams

If you have any questions, or I misunderstood your problem, feel free to ask.